# Where does one set the Oauth Redirect URI for Facebook apps?

Tags: facebook, firebase, facebook-apps, firebase-authentication

We are being asked to set the OAuth redirect URI for Facebook (as shown below) in the instructions to set up Google Firebase to use Facebook login.

We clicked in every menu for our app. Where is it? Could it be called something different?

From the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/facebook-login#before_you_begin):

> ...make sure your OAuth redirect URI (e.g. my-app-12345.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler) is listed as one of your OAuth redirect URIs in your Facebook app's settings page on the Facebook for Developers site in the Product Settings > Facebook Login config.

Answer (score 277, accepted):

I had a hard time finding this setting too.

If you are on `https://developers.facebook.com/`, you can find your apps listed in the top right, next to you profile picture. Selecting the app, will take you to the settings for that app.

In your app settings on `https://developers.facebook.com/sa/apps/<my-app-id>`, make sure that you add the <kbd>Facebook Login</kbd> product. Then under "Client OAuth Settings" enter the URL in the "Valid OAuth redirect URIs" box.

Comment: When you say "app settings" on https://developers.facebook.com/ where are you seeing them? We see all sorts of advertisements. We see developer settings. We see company settings. We also see "my apps" then if we click our app we don't see where to add products.

Comment: Added that info too. I'm glad I'm not the only one who has a hard time navigating.

Comment: Great that worked. Clicked "Add Product" from the left side of the screen and then chose Facebook login and then saw the Oauth options.

Comment: Just wasted 30 minutes trying to figure out how to set this.  Why not update the Firebase documentation to show this (even though it's really a Facebook complexity / poor UI issue).  Sonofafrikkinb!  Thanks for the answer Frank.

Comment: But in my developer window i m still unable to find the same @FrankvanPuffelen as there are various other options available but not the Client OAuth ont!

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen its showing trends,Active users,recent installs but not any way to add OAuth links

Comment: See this: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/<YOUR-APP-ID>/fb-login/quickstart/

Answer (score 129):

According to new changes in the facebook developers website UI,You can find it over here.Giving an image by image steps to find it.

1.Click on the Add product as in the image below.

[image]

2.You get a screen like this.In that you will see a list of products Facebook provides.In the image you can't see facebook login because I have already added it.

[image]

3.Click on settings of Facebook login.

[image]

4.You will get the required screen showing Client OAuth Login and the field for entering the redirect URL.

[image]

Comment: what will be the url?
My app name is FirebaseLogin.

Comment: You can get your redirect URL from the firebase console by going to Authentication->Facebook.Just copy paste over to here.Hope it helps.

Comment: That is a really good guide. I did it step by step and also added the redirect URI which I got from my firebase console. But still I can't log in with facebook. My android application was just working fine but all of a sudden I started getting this error : "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains." Can you help me with that please ?

Comment: Thanks!! the new Dashboard changes are confusing.. your screenshots helped a lot.:)

Comment: I want to add the "Facebook Login" product, but the "Products +" line is disabled!!!
How do I fix it?

Answer (score 16):

1- Go to your Firebase Console -> Authentication -> SIGN-IN METHOD -> Facebook. You'll find that link below your App Secret and App ID. Copy it. (It should be something like this: https://your-app-id.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler)

2- Go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ -> your app -> Product -> Facebook Login (add it if didn't yet) -> Settings. Past the link you've copied into "Valid OAuth redirect URIs" box.

Answer (score 15):

According to the ***2024*** new Facebook Developer website UI, once you create your app, it will show the dashboard page. Now follow these steps:

1. Click on the ***Use cases*** option:
   [image]
2. Then in the ***Authentication and account creation section***, click the ***Customize*** button:
   [image]
3. Then in the ***Settings*** section, click the ***Go to settings*** button:
   [image]
4. Scroll down a little bit, until you find the ***Valid OAuth Redirect URIs*** section:
   [image]

Here you can add your OAuth Redirect URI and then click the ***Save changes*** button below it.

Answer (score 8):

Its not there in settings anymore. You can find an option "+ Add Product" in the left menu. Select that & then select "Facebook link". There you'll find a box to paste the link.

**BTW, this can change whenever FB decides to redesign their Menu UI**

Answer (score 2):

look left bar, under the PRODUCTS title, and double click **facebook Login** title.

Answer (score 2):

FB is looking for an OAuth Redirect string that looks like this: https://`firebaseappname`.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler

FirebaseConsole provides it here: `Firebase` -> `Authentication` -> `Sign-in Method` -> `Facebook`

The  `[Save Changes]` button on FB developer portal was very glitchy, save changes -> reload page -> verify your `OAuth Redirect` entry persisted.