# can't find Client OAuth Settings section in my facebook app console

Tags: ios, facebook, oauth, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using the new [firebase](https://firebase.google.com) to create a project, in my project, I want to use Facebook for user authentication, I followed [this](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/facebook.html) instruction to create Facebook app, in the instruction it says:

> In your Facebook app configuration, click on the Settings tab on the
>   left-hand navigation menu. Then go to the Advanced tab at the top and
>   scroll down to the Client OAuth Settings section. At the bottom of
>   that section, add
>   https://auth.firebase.com/v2//auth/facebook/callback
>   to your Valid OAuth redirect URIs and click Save Changes at the bottom
>   of the page.

But in the **Advanced** tab of Facebook app console, I can't find **Client OAuth Settings** section. Anyone knows why?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37449761/where-does-one-set-the-oauth-redirect-uri-for-facebook-apps/37449912#37449912

Answer (score 9):

I guess you want Facebook login. In this case, you need to add "Facebook Login" as a product first.

In your Facebook app configuration, below Settings, click "Add Product", then choose "Facebook login". 
(You can set Oauth settings afterwards at "Facebook Login")

Comment: absolutely not a reply to the question. What if Facebook login has been already created many time ago, then how to acces the oauth ??  https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ID-OF-YOUR-APP/fb-login/settings/  <-- this url will redirect to you to the page where you can set oauth settings